# WebApi forward stream to other service

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a problem with .NET Core 1.0 and WebAPI. I wanted to do simple controller that will forward data stream coming into PUT method to another REST service without any need to store this data in memory.
In classic ASP.NET WebAPI there is no problem to do this using this code:

```
    public async Task Put(string id)
    {
        var fileContent = this.Request.Content;
        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("XXX", "XXX") })
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://X.X.X.X/documents");

                var response =
                    await client.PutAsync(string.Format("?uri={0}.xml", id), fileContent);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Created("urltocontent", "empty");
                }
                else
                {
                    BadRequest();
                }

            }
        }
```

But on .NET Core 1.0 ASP.NET WebAPI I'm getting error saying that the stream was already consumed. Below I've attached .NET Core code. I think that I've tried everything but I'm still getting this error. 
Is it a bug or feature of .NET Core and I have to do it in different way?

```
    public async Task Put(string id)
    {
        Stream fileContent = Request.Body;
        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("XXX", "XXX") })
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://X.X.X.X/documents");

                var payload = new StreamContent(fileContent);

                var response =
                    await client.PutAsync(string.Format("?uri={0}.xml", id), payload);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Created("urltocontent", null);
                }
                else
                {
                    BadRequest();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Request body streams by default can only be read once. If it's already read, then there's something else reading it. If you don't specify `id` in your query string, then that binding would read the body looking for `id` (I think). Try adding a `[FromQuery]` to your parameter; if that doesn't fix it, then something else earlier in the pipeline is reading the body.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that but it didn't help :( One thing is that when I change logic to save this stream do disk using FileStream instead of forwarding it everything works great.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this initialized the payload inside the `using`:

```
    public async Task Put(string id)
    {
        Stream fileContent = Request.Body;
        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("XXX", "XXX") })
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://X.X.X.X/documents");

                using (var payload = new StreamContent(fileContent))
                {
                    var response =
                        await client.PutAsync(string.Format("?uri={0}.xml", id), payload);

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        Created("urltocontent", null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        BadRequest();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nope, this didn't help. In the meantime I've tried using plain old HttWebRequest and it worked but I had to use stream CopyTo and this consumes memory so it's not an option.